# Calling java code from javascript adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Facing the below issue when trying to invoke java code from javascript adapters with Mobilefirst 8.0.

Sample code from the below link is used for testing.

https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/Adapters/tree/release80

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8dHT.png)

com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl E FWLST0904E: Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: subtractTwoIntegers in adapter: UsingJavaInJavaScriptAdapters
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.sample.customcode.Calculator] is not a function, it is object. (UsingJavaInJavaScriptAdapters-impl.js#24)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3951)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3929)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3962)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3981)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4036)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4024)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2502)

Answer (score 2):

This normally happens when your server is running a version of Java that is different from the one with which the adapter was built.For example, MFP server is running on JDK 1.7, while the adapter has been built using JDK 1.8.

Ensure your server is running the same version of Java that is used to build the adapters.

Comment: Verfied this. Both server and adapter are using JDK 1.8.